# SQL query not retrieving data

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE,'MONTH') creation_month  
FROM 
    AP_INVOICES_ALL;
```

This query retrieves the month properly. But if I pass the month in where clause it doesn't retrieve data.

```
SELECT DISTCINT
    TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'MONTH') CREATION_MONTH  
FROM
    AP_INVOICES_ALL
WHERE 
    TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'MONTH') = 'MARCH';
```

Please assist. I need to pass month as parameter in one report.

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve] for details on how to ask a question. Some details on what you want to see happen (examples etc) would be good too.

Comment: I assume, it is PL-SQL? Could it be that statement is  case sensitve?

Comment: I don't understand your query. If the parameter is MARCH, then it will only return one row with one value that is... MARCH. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with `'MONTH'` formats.  The string is padded with characters.

Instead, use `'MON'`.  Check this out:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'MONTH'), 
       (case when to_char(sysdate, 'MONTH')= 'APRIL' then 1 else 0 end),
       to_char(sysdate, 'MON'), 
       (case when to_char(sysdate, 'MON')= 'APR' then 1 else 0 end)
from dual;
```

The first `case` expression returns 0 -- no match.  The second returns 1, indicating that they do match.

Answer (score 0):

I think passing in just the month, without the year, is not a good idea. And you will be far better off treating dates as dates, comparing them to dates, etc. Might I suggest something like the following?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(creation_date, 'MONTH') AS creation_month
  FROM ap_invoices_all
 WHERE TRUNC(creation_date, 'MONTH') = DATE'2018-03-01';
```

`TRUNC()`ing the date to the month will return a value of type `DATE` of the first of the month at midnight. You can then compare using regular Oracle `DATE` values or ANSI `DATE` literals as above.

Hope this helps.